# How can i use Javascript to access an array of hyperlinks in a HTML doc using Legacy Dom and W3C Dom?

Tags: javascript, dom

For example i have an array of links:

```
var links = [
    <a href="One.com" id="one"></a>,
    <a href="Two.com" id="two"></a>,
    <a href="Three.com" id="three"></a>,
];

//W3S Dom
document.getElementById("one");

//Legacy DOM
document.getElementByTagName("a")
```

Is my way of accessing the links using the W3C DOM method and legacy DOM correct?

How can I then go on to create a for loop to access the array using the two different methods?

Comment: "For example i have an array of links" — That is a syntax error, not an array of links (or anything).

Comment: "Is my way of accessing the links using the W3C DOM method and legacy DOM correct?" — Does it do what you want? Does it throw any errors?

Comment: `document.getElementByTagName` doesn't exist, and the method with a similar name that actually exists is DOM 1 not Legacy.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a little snippet with example :

```js
// Use string in you want an array of HTML element
var linksArray = [
    '<a href="One.com" id="one"></a>',
    '<a href="Two.com" id="two"></a>',
    '<a href="Three.com" id="three"></a>',
];
console.log(linksArray[0]);

// You can use object if you want specific key to call element 
var linksObj = {
    'one'  : '<a href="One.com" id="one"></a>',
    'two'  : '<a href="Two.com" id="two"></a>',
    'three': '<a href="Three.com" id="three"></a>',
};
console.log(linksObj.one);

// If you want to get un element by id, you need him to be in your DOM before
var one = document.getElementById("one");
console.log(one);

// If you want to get element by tag name, you can do something like this to get an HTML collection of your "<a>" elements :
var element = document.getElementById("div");
var tag = element.getElementsByTagName("a");
console.log(tag);
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <a href="One.com" id="one"></a>
  <a href="Two.com" id="two"></a>,
  <a href="Three.com" id="three"></a>
</div>
```

The documentation for the **getElementsByTagName** : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

Hope it helps !